# Can I post my own message in Facebook "Real Time App Activity" (apps ticker)?

Tags: facebook, ticker

Is it possible to post my own message and publish it on the app ticker whenever i want?
(Not talking about the general ticker on users feed, but the one you have when you enter an app)

For example: Every time a user logged in, facebook publish a message in app ticker (on the right) that the user started to play the app.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is publishing an action.
For a high-level explanation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/#news-feed
For the tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can set specific Open Graph actions for your application that will be viable to appear in the app ticker. I do not think there is anyway to FORCE facebook to display your action.
You can read more here about the [Open Gaph Protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).